# Difference in SkiaSharp measureText and System Drawing's measureText

Tags: c#, cross-platform, system.drawing, skiasharp

I am trying to find out the a character's width and height in windows environment using this code:

```
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(800,550)))
{
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString("0",new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 10) , new PointF(0, 0), 
            StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        Console.WriteLine(size.Height);
        Console.WriteLine(size.Width);
}
```

The output is:
Height: 15.104165
Width: 8.001301

I am trying to port this process to cross platform code using SkiaSharp using this code:

```
using (SKPaint p = new SKPaint
           {
               IsAntialias = true, Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("monospace"),
               TextSize = 10
           })
    {
            string text = "0" ;
            SKRect textBounds = SKRect.Empty;
            p.Color = SKColors.Black;
            p.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
            p.MeasureText(text, ref textBounds);
            Console.WriteLine(textBounds.Height);
            Console.WriteLine(textBounds.Width);
    }
```

This is the height and width of same character in SkiaSharp:
Height: 7
Width: 5

Can I get some help regarding this?
What am I missing?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357697/8170844) answer regarding GraphicsUnit. GDI+ defaults to GraphicsUnit.Point (which will depend on your screen's dpi and app's dipAware settings) whereas SkiaSharp defaults to [pixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skpaint.textsize?view=skiasharp-2.88).

Comment: @Yitz thank you for the article. Is there any way to make the conversion between Point and Pixel, regardless of DPI settings?

Comment: Not really, points is 1/72 of an inch and you need to know your dpi to find out how many pixels that translates to. You could look at the Horizontal/VericalResolution properties of your Bitmap or DpiX/Y properties of your graphics to see what the default is in your environment, but that text on that bitmap will look different if you ran that program on a different dpi screen.

Comment: @AliAhmad you are using generic font families, for me the skia resolves monospace to SegoeUI while GDI resolves it to Courier New. This will more likely yield different measurement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I measure text in millimeter given a font size in pt with `System.Drawing`:

```cs
static double PtToMm(double pt) { return pt * 25.4 / 72.0; }

var familyName = "Arial";
var fontHeightPt = 10.0f;

using var font = new Font(familyName, fontHeightPt, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.World);
using var graphicsImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
graphicsImage.SetResolution(300.0f, 300.0f);
using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(graphicsImage);
using var stringFormat = (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone();
// System.Drawing doesn't measure trailing whitespace on default
// stringFormat.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
var nullPoint = new PointF(0, 0);

var textBounds = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, nullPoint, stringFormat);
var totalWidthMm = PtToMm(textBounds.Width);
var totalHeightMm = PtToMm(textBounds.Height);
```

With SkiaSharp, everything is a bit different. This is my current solution:

```cs
using var fontManager = SKFontManager.CreateDefault();
using var typeface = fontManager.MatchFamily(familyName, SKFontStyle.Normal);

using var fontPaint = new SKPaint
{
  IsAntialias = true,
  HintingLevel = SKPaintHinting.Normal,
  TextAlign = SKTextAlign.Left,
  TextSize = (float)PtToMm(fontHeightPt),
  Typeface = typeface,
};
var textBounds = new SKRect();
var totalWidthMm = fontPaint.MeasureText(Text, ref textBounds);
var totalHeightMm = textBounds.Height;

// textBounds.Width => width of text without leading/trailing whitespace
// textBounds.Left => width of leading whitespace
```

If you want to measure the text with leading but without trailing whitespace:

```cs
var totalWidthMm = fontPaint.MeasureText(Text.AsSpan().TrimEnd(), ref textBounds);
```